# Open resource for spectroscopic raw data

Tags: physical-chemistry, spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy, databases

Is anyone aware of reliable resources (ideally public) which allow the user to download the raw spectroscopic data such as infrared spectrum of small organic molecules, or rotational spectrum of HCl/DCl mixtures or NMR spectra of molecules? I was looking at the NIST database but apparently there is no option for downloading the spectrum as an Excel, csv or txt file. Thanks.

[NIST Spectral Database](https://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/vib-ser/)

Comment: Excellent question! The last time I needed an IR spectrum, for ethyl acrylate, I had to settles for a JCAMP format file and hack it to get data into a simple .txt file I could use. I hope a good answer appears!

Comment: @EdV If working with a Windows computer, try JDXview (cf. my answer).

Comment: @EdV: JCAMP-DX is actually pretty self-explanatory and easy (unless it's in one of the weird compressed subformats) - says the maintainer of a number of spectroscopic file format import filters for R... ;-) ... who is usually *very* wary of .txt or Excel files since the converters usually throw away lots of meta-information that may have been available.

Comment: @cbeleitesunhappywithSX Very good point! But the ultimate reason I need ASCII text files is that they are used with my free LightStone simulation software that instantiates both the Jones optical calculus and the Mueller optical calculus. If you are interested at all, please send me an e-mail at evoigtman@icloud.com and I will send along a link to my website and a couple of published papers that explain what I have developed over 30 years.

Answer (score 7):

As a quick fix: To access the IR spectral data of $\ce{HCl}$, I opted for a seach by (Hill) formula  on [NIST's](https://webbook.nist.gov/chemistry/form-ser/) web page, which yielded three entries [here](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Formula=HCl&NoIon=on&Units=SI).  For $\ce{HCl}$ in particular ([here](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7647010&Units=SI&Mask=80#IR-Spec)) I opted for the first one [here](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C7647010&Units=SI&Type=IR-SPEC&Index=0#IR-SPEC), indeed offering the spectrum as image file or as JCAMP-DX.

As in the comment by `@EdV`, this JCAMP-DX an ASCII file indeed.  Note [JDXview](http://merian.pch.univie.ac.at/~nhaider/cheminf/jdxview.html) by Norbert Haider (Department of Drug Synthesis, University of Vienna, Austria) is a very handy program (only 560 kb, installation free executable) for a quick display of this file by NIST. *Via* File -> Save, the export of the data in a two-column, tabulator separated `.txt` file is just a click away.  The program works perfectly well in Windows, and with `wine` libraries equally in Linux, too.  (The author equally distributes the underlying Delphi / Pascal code.)

---

*Note 1:* Because of the tags `physical chemistry`, and `spectroscopy`, you may be interested in a python module like [jcamp](https://github.com/nzhagen/jcamp) to access either IR, or NMR spectra in the JCAMP-DX formats (there are multiple).

*Note 2:* Sometimes, all you have indeed is an image (a scanned) spectrum.  If you pay attention and proceed in sections (e.g., $4000 - 2000$, then $2000 - 800\,\pu{cm^{-1}}$) to account for the break on the abscissa in IR spectroscopy, a digitizer like [WebPlotDigtizer](https://automeris.io/WebPlotDigitizer/) may be worth to use.  If you want, the program works *via* a web browser, installation free, with «normal image files» like `.png`, and since some time with images embedded in a `.pdf` (think about publications), too.

Comment: (+1) Even better than the good answer I hoped for! Many thanks: I just got a new windows laptop yesterday, dumped the “S” kiddie mode and I will download the JDXview program ASAP.

Comment: Thanks for a very useful response. Can we use the spectra for publication purposes i.e., NIST data open to re-use? I wanted to try out a new deconvolution algorithm to enhance resolution on rotational spectra or vibrational spectra.

Comment: @M.Farooq Re use of NIST data for a publication: I do think it is possible because there is a note how to cite parts / all of it (https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Contrib=). Wider use probably is a case for Customer support (data@nist.gov, Expiration Date: 06/30/2021, https://www.nist.gov/srd/standard-reference-data-contact-form).  An other source _might_ be the SDBS spectra collection (https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp): «If more [than 50] spectra are required for some specific purpose or commercial use, you should consult us and describe the intended usage or purpose of our SDBS.»

Comment: @M.Farooq: (still SDBS spectra collection): https://sdbs.db.aist.go.jp/sdbs/LINKS/contact_eng.html.  Re IR-data, I _speculate_ sources like Aldrich, Hummel, Sadtler, Biorad/KnowItAll, Specinfo (Wiley, https://application.wiley-vch.de/stmdata/specinfo.php) equally probably require contact prior engaging such a work because they invested time / man power / infra structure into their databases and obtaining (c) clearance from the publishers of primary publication.

Comment: @M.Farooq Maybe IR:  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27795739 / http://osdb.info/ which seems to be dormant a little in comparison to the Raman sibling COD/ROD (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6557180/, https://solsa.crystallography.net/rod/) which by intent is open domain.

Comment: I think the NIST data is digitized version of really old spectra from Coblintz Society. What if one takes a journal permission for a figure and digitize it for testing the resolution algorithm, like as you said WebPlotDigitizer? It is such a grey area.

Comment: @M.Farooq What qualifies as «small molecule» here?  Small molecules (organic synthesis / solution NMR) typically are larger than those inspected for their rotational spectra (diluted gas / low T / low p).  The latter a topic for atmospheric / astrochem (e.g., http://vpl.astro.washington.edu/spectra/, http://vpl.astro.washington.edu/spectra/allmoleculeslist.htm). | With IR spectroscopy in chemometrics (e.g., PCA), there is much of work re (IR spectroscopy) .AND. ((machine learning) .OR. (neuronal network)), too (e.g., retired https://www2.chemie.uni-erlangen.de/services/telespec/ by 1990s.).

Comment: By small molecules, I meant rotational spectra (< 300 formula weight). I just wanted to test the deconvolution process on simple spectra HCl/DCl mixture which is partially resolved. BTW thanks for pointing out open access Raman spectra.

Comment: Wrt digitizing, years ago the Analytical Chemistry department at TU Dresden had a student preparing scans and digital band tables for the spectra in the Schrader-Meier Atlas. I have no idea whether/under what conditions these are available, but the Schrader-Meier Atlas itself now falls under the "orphaned book" exceptions of German copyright law.

Answer (score 2):

This is "such as":

- For Raman spectra of minerals, there's the [RRUFF database](https://rruff.info/)
  They use a JCAMP-DX-like ASCII format
- Raman spectra of a number of small molecules important in biochemistry (amino acids, sugars, some fatty acids):
  [De Gelder, J.; De Gussem, K.; Vandenabeele, P. & Moens, L.: Reference database of Raman spectra of biological molecules J Raman Spectrosc, 2007, 38, 1133-1147](http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/jrs.1734). They send the spectra upon asking, IIRC as Matlab file.

Comment: Thank you. I sent a request to the author. This article is from 2007, let us if the email is still valid or if they are willing to respond.

Comment: The authors did not bother to respond.