# Open source for atomic spectra raw data

Tags: physical-chemistry, computational-chemistry, spectroscopy

Is anyone aware of a open source atomic spectra database? In particular I am looking for high resolution Na atomic emission which can be downloaded in csv or Excel. I am aware of NIST but I could not find a atomic spectrum. Secondly do they allow re-use of their figures? Thanks.

Comment: Any US government publications can be distributed and copies at will. One should certainly be ethically honest and acknowledge the source, but there is no fee for use.

Comment: It is a tricky situation in a publication. I want to publish a spectrum. Sometimes, the copyright is held by another publisher. Many IR spectra don't belong to NIST but they have been digitized from very old commercial catalogues.

Comment: [Do I need reprint permission to use material from a NIST publication?](https://www.nist.gov/nist-research-library/library-faqs) --- "In general, publications of the National Institute of Standards and Technology, as publications of the Federal government, are in the public domain and not subject to copyright in the United States. Permission to reprint or copy from them is therefore not required. The original source should be credited. ..." // It *in general*, I'd think that webpages fall under unlimited use.

Comment: Okay, thanks. That sounds encouraging.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open resource for spectroscopic raw data](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/130994/open-resource-for-spectroscopic-raw-data)

Comment: No Cody, I had asked that question. I am asking for a downloadable spectrum of Na.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your [previous question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/130994/open-resource-for-spectroscopic-raw-data) and your comment above in lines of «NIST's policy to use published data may be fine» I question if your literature search included a visit at [NIST's Handbook of Basic Atomic Spectroscopic Data](https://www.nist.gov/pml/handbook-basic-atomic-spectroscopic-data).

In the case of [sodium](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/sodiumtable1_a.htm), recorded lines for either air or vacuum are listed next to the data about *persistent lines*, and analogue data about the single ionized form.  While not yet in a `.csv` format, copy-paste into an editor is eased because you may toggle between the output to be table-like [formatted](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/sodiumtable2.htm) form, or [ASCII](https://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/sodiumtable2_a.htm).

*Addition:*

An alternative could be to digitize emission spectra like the following:

[image]

([reference](http://physicsopenlab.org/2017/09/07/spectral-lines-broadening/), final spectrum about the *hot high pressure* sodium lamp)

Comment: Thanks Buttonwood, I was looking for an entire real "spectrum", as the output from a detector, so that one could look at the peak shapes.

Comment: @M.Farooq Please have a look if an emission spectrum like the added one suits your interest better.  Equally, I created a chat room for this at https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111693/apropos-sodium